# Summation with negative factorial terms

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, factorial, poisson-distribution

My problem arises in trying to prove that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n\lambda^n}{n!}=\lambda e^\lambda$$

So what I did was

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n\lambda^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!}=\lambda\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\lambda e^\lambda$$

, where I considered the taylos expansion of the exponential $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n / n!$ for the last step.

But I'm not okay with the logic here (even if my probable wrongdoings took me to the correct answer).

My main concern is that in the last sum we have a negative factorial in the denominator for the $n= 0$ term, and as far as I know this is an undefined quantity. We could avoid mentioning this by skipping this undefined term and doing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ instead of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ but how could then I justify me ignoring a term that is possibly not zero in that series?

I guess my question can be rephrased as why the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ can be both $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n / n!$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{(n-1)} / (n-1)! = \sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}x^k / k!$ at the same time?

Comment: The first term of the sum is zero, so you can start the sum at $n=1$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Mmmm the first term is $\lambda^{-1}/(-1)!$ as far as I can tell. Which is not zero but undefined (since negative factorials are not defined).

Comment: To be very concrete about the nature of your error: $n! = n \cdot (n - 1)!$ is true for $n \geq 1$, but in your first step you erroneously applied this identity at $n = 0$ (cancelling $\frac{n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}$ in the $n = 0$ term), introducing the undefined $(-1)!$.  (As a matter of developing mathematical maturity, I would say: you got half-way to diagnosing your error; the next thing you should have done, after realizing you'd produced a formula with nonsense in it, is gone looking for the exact spot in your argument that the nonsense appeared.)

Comment: Practically , factorial of a negative integer is $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term of the series is $$\frac{0\times\lambda^0}{0!}=0$$
The rest of the series is $$\lambda\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

Now re-index this with $i=n-1$ to give $$\lambda\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}=\lambda e^{\lambda}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\Gamma(n)$, for $n \leq 0$ is essentially $\pm \infty$ and gives $\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(-n)} = 0$. This applies to the series as
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \, t^n}{n!} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{(-1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-1)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-1)!} = t + \frac{t^2}{1!} + \cdots \\
&= t \, \left( 1 + \frac{t}{1!} + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots \right) \\
&= t \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!} = t \, e^t.
\end{align}

In a similar manor consider the series:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 \, t^n}{n!} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n(n-1) + n) \, t^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-1)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{(-2)!} + \frac{t}{(-1)!} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} + t \, e^t \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+2}}{n!} + t \, e^t \\
&= t \, (t+1) \, e^t.
\end{align}

Alternatively, using differential operators,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \, t^n}{n!} &= t \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \, t^{n-1}}{n!} \\
&= t \, \frac{d}{dt} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!} = t \, \frac{d}{dt} \left( e^t \right) \\
&= t \, e^t.
\end{align}